# context is null after adding new column/property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been modifying my existing project in mvc-c# and add a new column in one my tables.

Now, I modified my model and add this column **polads**

```
  [Table("media_order_headers")]
public class OrderHeader
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    /*list of other columns here */
    public byte active { get; set; }
    public byte with_package { get; set; }
    public byte polads { get; set; } //newly added column
```

So now, i have added this to my Add and Edit controllers

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody]OrderHeaderViewModel model)
    {
        OrderHeader ord = new OrderHeader
        {
            /*list of other property value assigning*/
           confirmed = model.confirmed,
            with_package = model.with_package,
            polads = model.polads
        };
        _context.OrderHeader.Add(ord);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromBody]OrderHeaderViewModel model)
    {
       var ord = await _context.OrderHeader.Where(f => f.id == model.id).FirstOrDefaultAsync<OrderHeader>();
        if (ord != null)
        {
    
            ord.with_package = model.with_package;
            ord.billing_guide_no = model.bgnumber;
            ord.polads = model.polads;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have not encountered a problem on Add function but in Edit Function.

It doesnt show exception error but it says on the console is internal server error 500. My variable **ord** is null.  When I  _context for internal exceptions it shows object not set to an instance of an object.

I have put a breakpoint on this line of script:
`var ord = await _context.OrderHeader.Where(f => f.id == model.id).FirstOrDefaultAsync<OrderHeader>();`

The view is returning set of values from the form.

my question is that, what might be the reason for this null error if it works with Add controller?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you execute ef core database update command? Seems like you don't have such column in database.

Comment: @DmitriyGrebennikov is right, you need to add new migration and then update database (if this is code-first approach), otherwise you'll need to use scaffold command

Comment: Hi @DmitryGrebennikov Im not using MVC core, im still at MVC 5 using VS 2015... Is that available on MVC 5? How to do that?

Comment: Please read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell

Comment: Hi @DmitryGrebennikov, this is for EF Core, im not using EF Core/MVC Core... is there other way to do this update?

Comment: Also, ensure you are [targeting .NET 4.5 or newer in your web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#before-getting-started).

Comment: Hi everyone, it seems that my fault is that the datatype on my sql for the column polads is set to bit while on my model, its datatype is byte. Im having a null reference error because of the mismatched column datatype. Your ideas were highly appreciated